# error in R h2o h2o.uploadFile

Tags: r, file-io, upload, h2o

I am trying the tutorial from http://www.r-bloggers.com/diving-into-h2o/

I downloaded some of the airlines data locally.  I am able to connect R to an H2O instance and run the demo, but I am not able to upload the airlines data successfully with an h2o function.   I am not getting an error either.   This is what happens:

```
library(data.table)
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init()
DTair <- fread(pathAirline)
dim(DTair)
[1] 7009728      29
air2008.hex = h2o.uploadFile(localH2O, path = pathAirline, destination_frame  = "air2008.hex", parse = FALSE)
dim(air2008.hex)
[1] -1 -1
```

When I import with the fread() function, I get the data as expected.  When I try to use h2o.uploadFile() I don't see any errors but the object has dimensions -1 by -1.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The H2OConnection object (your `localH2O` object) is no longer supposed to be passed in to any of the uploadFile/importFile functions (it was deprecated), so you should remove argument that from the function.  Also, you should use the default, `parse = TRUE`, if you actually want to read the data in.

Also, it is recommended to use the `h2o.importFile` instead of `h2o.uploadFile` since it is multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

The pdf documentation for h2o.uploadFile shows that all the arguments are optional except for path.   I was able to successfully upload the file with:

```
air2008.hex = h2o.uploadFile(path = pathAirline)
```